Integrating Power BI log data to splunk to create alerts in splunk
I have a scenario where if the power bi dataset gets failed..on failed status I have to get an alert from splunk stating that dataset failed with the failed reason...how to get log information from power bi service portal to splunk and how to create an alert based on that data in splunk
I don't have any idea how to implement this
